# Foundation Side Navigation Trouble

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am having trouble with Side Navigation, see [codePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emmWMP). With Foundation 5 example, I tried to put blue label on sides (side1, side2, side 3, etc) to be same level with first label (My Site), I add padding-top, padding-down, and something else that are not working. I would be greatly appreciate of your help to set side navigation and proper text center with less space between.

CSS

```
.topside-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 1.25rem; 
  padding-right: 2.25rem;
  margin: -60px 2px 5px 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Foundation - [Side Nav](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/sidenav.html)

It is very time consuming and please suggest me the best way, I already did test Chrome Developer Tools and CodePen. Still not figuring out why foundation website doesn't provide instruction clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `margin-top: 0` to `.top-bar ul`, and set `line-height:65px` to `.topside-nav li`

Comment: Thank you alot, it does solve the problem, oh man it is confusion easily.  I wonder about navigation bar's width 100% to be more flexible on responsive?  Use width:100% under .topside-nav?

Comment: If you set .topside-nav to max-width:100%, then it will be more responsive.